Jetpack compose create dynamic row & column based on header length
Here i have a requirement I have data like this [{“header”:”Test”,”value”:”value1”},{“header”:”Test1”,”value”:”value2”},{“header”:”Test1122222”,”value”:”value3”},{“header”:”Test4”,”value”:”value4”},{“header”:”Tes5”,”value”:”value5”},{“header”:”Test7”,”value”:”value7”},{“header”:”Test8”,”value”:”value8”},{“header”:”Test9”,”value”:”value9”}] i have to create a table whose rows & column size create dynamically based on the header length .One row can contain ex 4 column another row can contain 7 column it should create based on header length character .
Here i have attached pic how it should look 

The best Solution i found and solved it by using ..
Flowlayout

[![enter image description here][1]][1]        import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyRow
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
    @Composable
    fun DynamicHeaderLayout(headers: List<String>, data: List<List<String>>) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(data.size) { rowIndex ->
            LazyRow {
                items(headers.size) { colIndex ->
                    Text(
                        text = data[rowIndex][colIndex],
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
      }
   }

val headers = listOf("Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3")
val data = listOf(
   listOf("Data 1.1", "Data 1.2", "Data 1.3"),
   listOf("Data 2.1", "Data 2.2", "Data 2.3"),
   listOf("Data 3.1", "Data 3.2", "Data 3.3")
 )

//Call this function to show data dynamically
DynamicHeaderLayout(headers = headers, data = data)

[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/EbNir.png Not the solutio this is how it looks it should fill the width of the screen
